# CloudFlare RocketLoader causing Woocommerce Add to Cart button to not load

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cloudflare

So I want to enable `CloudFlares` `Rocketloader` feature on my site as it significantly improves the load times of my page.

Thing is, the Add to Cart button doesn't load when it's enabled.

The `CloudFlare` documentation states:

> "You can have Rocket Loader ignore individual scripts by adding the
>   data-cfasync="false" attribute to the relevant script tag"

I think I need to add the above code to the correct script but I have no idea what the script is called or where it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ignore option doesn't always work (kind of complex). Is it just happening on a specific URL, such as yoursite.com/checkout? If yes, then you might want to look at turning off Rocket Loader on that URL with a [PageRule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-).

Comment: Hi, It happens on all my product pages which is pretty much the bulk of my website and the most important. If I refresh the page with the Rocket Loader turned on, then the button re-appears but most people who come to my site wont be refreshing.

Comment: Are your product pages something like yoursite.com/product? You could set a PageRule for that to turn off Rocket Loader.

Comment: Hi, I want to enable on my product pages because they take the longest to load. Its strange because RocketLoader use to work fine, the add to cart button showed up everytime but about a month ago it started acting up. Could have started around the time I update Woocommerce.

Comment: We push updates to Rocket Loader all the time & that could be a factor (it could also be a factor if the provider changed something about their JS as well).

Comment: @damoncloudflare Any solution for this? I got the same issue